# R Correlation Plots number instead of Text

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

When i plot the correlation, the column names are not displayed instead number gets displayed.

Why does this happen and how to rectify the same?

Below is the code

```
espAlltmNum <- espAlltm[, sapply(espAlltm, is.numeric)]
#above dataset is created as correlation needs only numeric columns
M <- cor(espAlltmNum,use = "pairwise", method = "pearson")
corrplot(M, method = "circle",tl.pos = "d",  tl.cex = 0.5, tl.col = 'black',
         order = "hclust", diag = TRUE,title = "Correlation Plot"
         , mar=c(1,1,1,1))
```

the output is:

[image]

Comment: How long are your column names? Maybe they are too long for the table cells? And what does `colnames(M)` return? – I don't have your data to try, but if the colum names are as you expect them, I would begin with removing all the arguments from `corrplot(M)` and then put them back in one by one until you find the culprit.

Comment: Also, it seems as if you have conflicting arguments: `tl.pos = "d"` puts the column names on the diagonal, and `diag = TRUE` puts the correlation coefficients on the diagonal. Try to delete one or the other from your code and see what happens.

Comment: Column names are of lengthy ones. colNames(M) returns NULL, and tried with diag=FALSE...but the plot still shows with number and not the text.  Also, the text used to come earlier, and i did restart of R server, deleted the prior charts and executed the whole code again. After this, the plot is showing up like this...

Comment: Try `colnames(M)`, not col**N**ames(M). And what happens if you delete `diag = TRUE` from your code? Also, it is very difficult for us to guess what is wrong, if you do not provide an example of "M" or "espAlltm". Can you `dput()` one of these?

Answer (score 0):

i see some issue with corrplot and GGally packages. If the correlation matrix is called before the GGally package/library, the matrix contains the column names(in text).

If the correlation matrix is called after the GGally package/library, matrix contains the index number of the column name. The plot too would give the index number as attached before...